# yaml file for conda packages update programmatically

Tags: python, anaconda, jinja2, conda, ruamel.yaml

I have a python script that would like to read a set of conda recipes and update them with some information (e.g. file: https://github.com/williamjamir/staged-recipes/blob/850760fb63c0fc000b95ac27680ec018fa94dcb7/recipes/pyexcel-ezodf/meta.yaml) :

I'm using this:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

from yaml.constructor import ConstructorError
from yaml.scanner import ScannerError

yaml = YAML(typ='jinja2')
yaml.allow_duplicate_keys = True
with open(file_name) as fp:
     yalm_file = yaml.load(fp)
```

When I'm printing the original file `yaml_file` using:

```
with open(path_file, 'w') as fp:
    yaml.dump(yaml_file, fp, allow_unicode=True, explicit_start=True)
```

The output contains a lot of tags and comments related to the type of 
 the data such as:

```
 --- !!python/object/apply:ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap
 dictitems:
 about: !!python/object/apply:ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap
 dictitems: {home: 'https://github.com/soedinglab/xxmotif', license: 
 GPLv3, license_file: LICENSE,
 summary: 'eXhaustive, weight matriX-based motif discovery in nucleotide sequences'}
state:
  _yaml_format: !!python/object/new:ruamel.yaml.comments.Format
    state: !!python/tuple
    - null
    - {_flow_style: false}
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dump()` method for a `YAML` instance doesn't take the parameters you provide (`allow_unicode=True, explicit_start=True`). As you didn't provide a full working program, I can only guess that you (also) do a `import ruamel.yaml as yaml` (or even `import yaml`).

The conversion done by the jinja2 plugin, that deals with the standard jinja2 template syntax (that normally is processed before parsing with the YAML parser) needs to be done while loading **and while dumping**. So you need to use the same `YAML(typ='jinja2')` instance to do so:

```
import sys
file_name = 'meta.yaml'

from ruamel.yaml import YAML

from yaml.constructor import ConstructorError
from yaml.scanner import ScannerError

yaml = YAML(typ='jinja2')
yaml.allow_duplicate_keys = True
yaml.indent(sequence=4, offset=2)
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
# yaml.explicit_start = True
with open(file_name) as fp:
     data = yaml.load(fp)

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

gives exactly your input on round-trip:

```
{% set name = "pyexcel-ezodf" %}
{% set version = "0.3.3" %}
{% set sha256 = "26ddddc61c6bbe2641a15964ba57eaf92a171478e7ed9efb9ae4db1567d0998
c" %}

package:
  name: {{ name|lower }}
  version: {{ version }}

source:
  fn: {{ name }}-{{ version }}.tar.gz
  # The github url is been used because the tar.gz from pypi is missing the CONT
RIBUTORS.rst file
  url: https://github.com/pyexcel/{{ name }}/archive/v{{ version }}.tar.gz
  sha256: {{ sha256 }}

build:
  noarch: python
  number: 0
  script: python setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed --record r
ecord.txt

requirements:
  build:
    - python
    - setuptools

  run:
    - python
    - lxml

test:
  imports:
    - ezodf


about:
  home: https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel-ezodf
  license: MIT
  license_family: MIT
  license_file: '{{ environ["RECIPE_DIR"] }}/LICENSE'
  summary: 'A Python package to create/manipulate OpenDocumentFormat files'
  description: |
    'ezodf is a Python package to create new or open existing' +
    'OpenDocument (ODF) files to extract, add, modify or delete document data' +
    'forked from dead project https://bitbucket.org/mozman/ezodf' +
    'format and to/from databases' +
    ''
  dev_url: https://github.com/pyexcel/pyexcel-ezodf

extra:
  recipe-maintainers:
    - williamjamir
```

You don't need to set `allow_unicode`, that is default for `YAML.dump()`.

Comment: @AnthonIt can be that the jupyter is overriding the YAML functionality.

Comment: I have no idea what jupyter is doing, but if your code is still `yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout, allow_unicode=True)` it should throw a `TypeError`. If loading and dumping is not done within the same context I have no clue where your `yaml` comes from, but in any case you can do `from ruamel.yaml import YAML; yaml = YAML(typ='jinja2')` just before you dump

Comment: I remove all the complexity in my script an only use your code for one example. I have this error: `  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ruamel/yaml/jinja2/__plug_in__.py", line 58, in write
    data = data.replace(k, self.reverse[k])
TypeError: expected bytes, bytearray or buffer compatible object`

Comment: I updated ruamel.yaml.jinja2, to version 0.2.2 that should now also work with Python 3.4

Comment: Fantastic. Sorry to bother you with all this

Comment: Hi @Anthon: I have managed to run and it works in Python 3.4. However, I have seen major changes in my original files see this example: https://gist.github.com/ypriverol/0418285abbe01861b8af356f3172f016 . `New white spaces`, `New return lines`, `Remove of " `

Comment: Another example: https://gist.github.com/ypriverol/9e3b6df5cd7110f0b97bda94451e78f7

Comment: I don't see any new return lines in those examples. What I do see is that you haven't read the manual about indenting sequences with 4 positions (and an offset for the `-`) and about preserving (superfluous) quotes. Try: `yaml.indent(sequence=4, offset=2)`, 
`yaml.preserve_quotes = True`, and 
`yaml.boolean_representation = ['False', 'True']`

Comment: I updated the program, to generate exactly your input on round-trip. Please accept this post if that works for you as well (on this input) and post any questions about other files as new questions.